# converter software for fortran 90/95 to fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77, fortran95

I have an old code with lots of subroutines, and they are all in Fortran 77, So now I want to update one subroutine which I need to update according to a Fortran 90/95 code, Is there any way to convert it to 77?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Usually you can mix Fortran 90/95 and FORTRAN 77...

Comment: Don't, just don't.  Very little of FORTRAN77 is not valid under the most recent versions of the language standard. You should program the new bits in Fortran 2003 and compile the whole lot together.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I use ifort.

Comment: Here is an (online) tool that could help you convert FORTRAN 77 code to Fortran 90 code: [SPAG](http://www.polyhedron.com/spag0html)... Not what you wanted, though...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yeah! But I have a code which Is written all in Fortran77 and since it is related to our research nobody cares about that now, until one day someone starts writing all in the new FORTRAN versions.

Comment: Don't, just don't.  And if anyone in your research group tells you that you must, go through the offices and labs and throw away anything  which was developed after 1977.  Start by deleting your web-browser, drop all mobile phones and tablets into buckets of acid, replace HP48s with slide rules, ...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  lol! that's true! but what can I do! It's what it is! They are old dudes!

Comment: So what you do is write code to fulfil the requirements, build the system and demonstrate it's excellence.  And you write it in a modern programming language, such as Fortran 2003, and integrate it with the old code base.  This is something that those of us working professionally with Fortran code bases do all the time.  If anyone tells me to write in FORTRAN77 I tell them to go forth and multiply.  Finally, this is my last word here, I have nothing more to write. Oh, actually my final words are *don't be ageist*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - It is hard to expect from everyone to start using F90. Afte all, it's a new version, has barely been here for 20 years ...

Comment: Put that cookie down, now!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: The Wiki page for Fortran 90 says the list of deleted features is empty, but by my understanding F77 had the "feature" that columns 73-80 could be used for comments if desired (if they were auto-punched with sequence numbers, a card sorter might care what they contained but the compiler wouldn't care in any case).  Did F90 remove that feature, or is there some means by which programs need to indicate whether a compiler should ignore everything past column 72?

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers have declarations that allow you to switch between fixed and free form Fortran-files.

As others have noted, use the newest compiler possible as they should be backwards compatible. Files are either in fixed form of free form and use the file endings `.f` or `.f90` to separate them.

If you absolutely need to, in Intel the directives are `!DIR$ FREEFORM` and `!DIR$ NOFREEFORM` if you need to control the reading of the file per line or section. This can be useful if you "have to" use old include-files written in fixed form but you want to use free form Fortran in you code, then you can write:

```
module important_new_code

<lots of use-statements>

!DIR$ NOFREEFORM
include 'old_style_includes.incl'
!DIR$ FREEFORM

<rest of module in modern fortran>

end module
```

However, this makes your code compiler-specific and is generally not a good idea! The best is always to fix your problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do. But as pointed out in the comments, you can mix Fortran 90/95 and Fortran 77 (but of course not in the same file). With ifort you could e.g. write an f90-file contaning you main program named file_1.f90 and another f77-file containing some subroutines called in in your main file which is named file_2.f77. To compile them together:

```
ifort -c file_1.f90
ifort -c file_2.f77
ifort file_1.o file_2.o -o file_1
```

In the first two lines you create object files (*.o) which you then link together creating a target file (here file_1). If you need further libraries you can link them in the usual way in the last line. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Note that while Fortran 90+ has no problems calling into Fortran 77 code, the other way round is not always the case. For example, a F90 subroutine that takes assumed-shape arrays (e.g. `INTEGER, DIMENSION(:) :: ARR`) cannot be called from F77 since such arguments are usually passed as descriptors (that's why F90 requires explicit interfaces for such subroutines) - a concept entirely alien to F77 compilers.